# Build iOS App having Google Sign with support for Mac

Tags: google-signin, macos-catalina, mac-catalyst

I have manually embedded the Google Sign In framework into an iOS app with the .bundle and .framework files.

After adding the Mac as deployment target with the most recent Xcode and macOS Catalina versions I get the following error message when trying to run the app on the Mac.

> Building for Mac Catalyst, but the linked framework 'GoogleSignIn.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator. You may need to restrict the platforms for which this framework should be linked in the target editor, or replace it with an XCFramework that supports both platforms.

Can I somehow fix this problem? Or do I have to wait for Google to release a new version of the framework that is compatible with both iOS and macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the framework is open source, you can open its Xcode project, enable Catalyst and recompile.

Comment: What should I do if the framework does not have an Xcode project?

Comment: And _where_ do you enable it?

Comment: There’s SUPPORT_CATALYST flag in Xcode project (or using command line as well)

Comment: @QuangVĩnhHà, still not works for me. Any idea why? (my custom framework)

Comment: Do you mean `SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST` ?